# What is the proper way to handle incorrect code in a post even after your edit has been rejected?

Tags: discussion

So I recently did an edit on a post:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9860959

The code that they had was incomplete and had errors and went against the meaning of functional programming since it hard coded the elements ID and on top of that used globals variables. I edited it to make the code actually work.

How do you handle these rejected edits? Can you contact anyone that reviewed it to get them to revert it or explain in more detail?

Comment: Never fix code errors in edits, answer with corrected code and explain instead.

Comment: Ah, is there a location of which I can find rules like these?

Comment: @TomC: In regards to edits, here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this is a duplicate of some other question, but the consensus if you find incorrect code in an answer: post a comment about the inaccuracies under the answer, downvote if the code is the sole purpose of the answer (so don't go around downvoting pseudocode or code with minor typos while the explanation of the code is decent) and post your own answer if you can show a better approach.